# Por que x[i] no toma el valor de i ingresado por el usuario?

Tags: javascript

El objetivo de este pequeño script es cambiar el contenido de uno de los spans en base a un numero ingresado por el usuario cuyo valor representa una posicion en el indice de la variable x

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("opciones");
        var i = document.getElementById("numeroDePagina").value;

        function mostrarPagina(){
            x[i].innerHTML = ":O";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: red; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: orange; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: yellow; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: green; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: blue; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: purple; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: fuchsia; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <br>
    Ingresa un numero del 0 al 6 para ver el resultado: 
    <input type="text" class="numeroDePagina"></input>
    <button onclick="mostrarPagina()">Haz clic</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas mal en el código.

1 - Debes de incluir en el código html de la página la etiqueta`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

2 - Las variables declaradas **x** e **y** debes declararlas dentro de la función **mostrarPagina()** ya que solo las usarás en esa función, no es necesario que sean variables globales.

3 - En la etiqueta del **input** `<input type="text" class="numeroDePagina"></input>` pusiste "class" en vez de "id"

Una vez dicho lo anterior, y con el código corregido de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function mostrarPagina(){

            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("opciones");
            var i = document.getElementById("numeroDePagina").value;

            x[i].innerHTML = ":O";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: red; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: orange; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: yellow; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: green; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: blue; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: purple; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <span class="opciones" style="background-color: fuchsia; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
    <br>
    Ingresa un numero del 0 al 6 para ver el resultado: 
    <input type="text" id="numeroDePagina"></input>
    <button onclick="mostrarPagina()">Haz clic</button>
</body>
</html>
```

El programa funcionará correctamente.

Comment: Ademas de que habia puesto class en lugar de id, por que las variables si son declaradas fuera de la funcion la funcion no funciona?

Comment: Puedes declarar la variable x fuera, porque cuando cargas la pagina, no estas obteniendo ningun valor de ella. Pero la variable "i" necesita tener un valor, es decir, lo que obtienes de la variable i es el .value y por lo tanto, cuando se carga la pagina por primera vez, el input con id "numeroDePagina" no tiene ningun valor, solo tendrá valor cuando lo introduzcas manualmente y le des al boton. El error que sale cuando declaras fuera ambas es un error de que no obtiene valor para la variable i.

Answer (score 0):

Tu variable `i` guarda el valor `""` ya que esta linea solo se ejecuta una vez al principio del programa y no es actualizada nuevamente, mira este ejemplo:

```js
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("opciones");

function mostrarPagina(){
  var i = document.getElementById("numeroDePagina").value;
  elementos[i].innerHTML = ":O";
}
```

```html
<span class="opciones" style="background-color: red; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
<span class="opciones" style="background-color: orange; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
<span class="opciones" style="background-color: yellow; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
<span class="opciones" style="background-color: green; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
<span class="opciones" style="background-color: blue; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
<span class="opciones" style="background-color: purple; padding: 10px; color: white;">:)</span><br><br><br>
<span class="opciones" style="background-color: fuchsia; padding: 10px;">:)</span><br><br><br>
<br>
Ingresa un numero del 0 al 6 para ver el resultado: 
<input type="text" id="numeroDePagina"></input>
<button onclick="mostrarPagina()">Haz clic</button>
```